# ADFS openid-configuration JSON metadata is encoded compared to AzureAD

Tags: asp.net, azure-active-directory, adfs, openid-connect

When I access the openid-configuration metadata for the ADFS I notice that the JSON document that is returned is encoded, of instance all "/" characters are escaped by "\" . I have not seen this behaviour when I access meta data for AzureAD. This causes a problem when trying to fetch the metadata using the ConfigurationManager:

```
ConfigurationManager<OpenIdConnectConfiguration> configManager = 
new ConfigurationManager<OpenIdConnectConfiguration>(stsDiscoveryEndpoint);
OpenIdConnectConfiguration config = configManager.GetConfigurationAsync().Result;
```

"issuer":"https://login.xxxxxx.com/adfs"

URL: https://login.xxxxxx.com/adfs/.well-known/openid-configuration

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turned out the issue was not related to any escaping in the JSON file. The error was caused by by the async operation that was fetching the document.

Error was:
IDX10803: Unable to create to obtain configuration from: 'https://login.dometic.com/adfs/.well-known/openid-configuration'.

The error went away when i changed from

```
configManager.GetConfigurationAsync().Result
```

to :

```
await configManager.GetConfigurationAsync().
```